# Porting query from JPQL to mongo using spring data mongo Criteria

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I've ported some of my `Entity` from `JPA` to document and now porting some of my queries.
here is the JPA query:

```
em.createQuery("select distinct c from CustomerImpl c left join fetch c.addresses ca where (:name is null or c.firstName LIKE :name or c.lastName LIKE :name) and (:ref is null or c.externalReference LIKE :ref) and (:city is null or ca.city LIKE :city) order by c.firstName").setParameter("name", name).setParameter("ref", customerRef).setParameter("city", city).getResultList();
```

below is my attempt :

```
    Criteria orNameCriteria = new Criteria().orOperator(Criteria.where("firstName").is(null), Criteria.where("firstName").is(name), Criteria.where("lastName").is(name));
    Criteria orCustomerRefCriteria = new Criteria().orOperator(Criteria.where("externalReference").is(null), Criteria.where("externalReference").regex(customerRef,"i"));
    Criteria orAddress = new Criteria().orOperator(Criteria.where("addresses.city").is(null), Criteria.where("addresses.city").regex(city, "i"));
    Query nameq = new Query(new Criteria().andOperator(orNameCriteria,orCustomerRefCriteria,orAddress));
```

this query return zero size arraylist. I've then changed the `orNameCriteria` to use is clause and making sure the data contained in `name` variable has `/` as suffix and prefix. That didn't work as well.

but queries from `mongoVue` and `RockMongo` clients :

```
{ firstName: /SAM/}
```

returns data.

**Question 1**: How do you write **LIKE CLAUSE** with spring-data-mongo `Criteria`?
**Question 2** : is that the right way to use or and and clause with `criteria`

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

Criteria.where("field").regex(pattern) should work

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have the ability add comments...

If you do a static import on Criteria, it will make your where clauses look a lot better.

Criteria orAddress = new Criteria().orOperator(where("addresses.city").is(null), where("addresses.city").regex(city, "i"));